# Create a PDF with lots (over a hundred) images

Tags: graphics

I have lots of images I need to display in a PDF (no text). I was hoping to make something like a contact sheet used for photos. Is there an easy way of doing this without having to do it all manually, i.e. can I set up, say, a 20 by 10 grid and then just list the filenames? If I have to go through and begin and end environments every few lines it's going to take way too long. Ideally, I'd like it to wrap onto the next page.

Comment: As long as the file names are predictive, this is quite easy. There are several packages that provide loops etc. You may want to look at `etoolbox`, plus you might need to know about `\IfFileExists{<file>}{yes}{no}`,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should give us more information about the code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure what information you want. I am asking for the best way of doing this so clearly I haven't coded this yet.

Comment: @daleif I have a list of the file names. I'm not trying to create code that finds the right files or anything like that. My question is how to display this easily without having to modify my list line-by-line.

Comment: Make the list into a comma separated list, then use `etoolbox` tools to loop over that list and include each one of them. The file test if useful if you make an error in making the list. Then use that construction as a starting point for how ever you wanted it to look like.

Comment: can you just add example of the list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading filenames from another file can be tricky as soon as there are special characters in the file name, such as `_` etc.

This uses `\readline`, which changes the catcodes accordingly and stores the read file name to a list, here called `\mylist`.

To display the graphics, it's 'sufficient' to define a list processor, basically doing `\includegraphics`. ( I added wrapping around after three images and used pretty alignment within table)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\listxadd{\mylist}{}
\newread\readhandle

\newcommand{\readfromfiletolist}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \begingroup
    \openin\readhandle=#1% open the file
    \endlinechar-1  % Drop the endline characters
    \loop
    \readline\readhandle to \linefromfile %read a complete line
    \listxadd{\mylist}{\linefromfile}% add expanded!
    \unless\ifeof\readhandle
    \repeat
    \endgroup
    \closein\readhandle% Close the file
  }{}%
}


\newcounter{piccounter}

\newcommand{\displayimage}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{piccounter}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{"#1"} \tabularnewline
  #1  
  \end{tabular}
  \ifnum\value{piccounter} = 3  % Wrap after 3 pictures
  \par
  \setcounter{piccounter}{0}%
  \fi%
}


\begin{document}
\readfromfiletolist{filelist.txt}
\begin{center}
\huge \textbf{Spot the wrong image!}
\end{center}

\forlistloop{\displayimage}{\mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the content of `filelist.text`

```
a_1.jpg
a_2.jpg
a_3.jpg
a_4.jpg
a_5.jpg
a_6.jpg
brontosaurs.png
a_7.jpg
```

The `brontosaurs.png` file is taken from [OpenClipart](https://openclipart.org/detail/32695/dinosaur-brontosaurus), while the nice beelike duke is taken from our ever friendly user Paulo Cereda!

Please note that `_` is displayed as a superscript dot, due to the catcode change. As long as the file name should not displayed itself, this is no issue, in my point of view.

Comment: Would it be more or less the same as locally redefine verbatiminput? That already have a lot of facilities in play and it should the be a matter of redoing its write command (not sure if it will work)

Comment: @daleif: Yes, I think you're right, but sometimes I am doing the hard way, just to learn how things work.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{"#1"}` just in case of blank space in file name

Comment: @touhami: Never used spaces in file names, I don't like them, but I will change my code, thanks for the hint

Comment: @ChristianHupfer see my update. You can misuse `\verbatiminput` for the line parsing.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for me with the " ". I don't have any spaces in my file names and it works well without.

Comment: @danm: Well, that was a suggestion by touhami. I had my solution without '"..."' first

Comment: @daleif: Seen, but I can't upvote again ;-)

Comment: Btw is it possible to center the captions? I can't work out where in the code we set the captions.

Comment: I just wanted to added so I know where it is and I can copy it next time. It will also work for the list question the other day.

Comment: @danm: Which captions? I got no captions there, The filename was just an indicator.

Comment: I meant the filenames. They are in fact quite a useful indicator!

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[t]{c}` instead of `\begin{tabular}[t]{l}` then ;-) `l` stands for left justified, `c` for `centered`, I leave it to you to figure out the correct letter for right justifying;-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this may work (untested)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,graphicx}
\newcommand\HandlePic[1]{%
   \includegraphics[width=3cm]{#1}
   \par
 }

 \forcsvlist\HandlePic{A,B,C}
```

Each item in the list is given one by one to the handler.

---

Just an addition to Christians solution. Here is a POC using the `verbatim` package to *misuse* `\verbatiminput`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand\test[1]{
  \begingroup
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    \includegraphics{\the\verbatim@line}%
    \par
  }
  \def\verbatim@input##1##2{%
   \IfFileExists {##2}{%
    \verbatim@readfile{\@filef@und}
    \endgroup\@doendpe}%
   {\typeout {No file ##2.}\endgroup}}
  \verbatiminput{#1}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{t.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the list in a file and read it in? There are over a hundred file names!

Comment: How are the images named? If it is just a common name and a number we don't even need the list. Plus how is the list of filenames formatted?

Comment: Also, I really need to format these images as I think this will take up more than a page and tell me that the dimensions were exceeded.

Comment: @danm: Reading it to a list is possible,with some work to do, assuming no spaces are in the name

Comment: Why, here the image is scaled to 3cms and is placed on a line of its own, so it changes page without problems

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, problable means **from** a file ;-)

Comment: The list is just a txt document with a filename on each line (order is important).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, didn't you give one of those read file constructions the other day? Thought I saw and example with it.

Comment: @daleif: Yes, yesterday... I am just copying it

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that should not need much extra to make it into a usable starting point.

Comment: @daleif: Well, it's not that easy as I've thought. I am struggling reading with the filenames in the list, or I am making a stupid mistake. Perhaps it's better to use `l3` stuff for this