# Automated document generation with texts and images

Tags: graphics, automation

I would like to generate a document including several images.
Under each image should be a different caption, taken from an text file, separated by line or semicolon.

For example:

```
imagename: 1.jpg

text file line 1: Description 1

Results to an image with caption placed in the document.
```

Furthermore I would like it arranged, about 4-6 images per page.

Comment: Where in all of this goes in _automation_? I think you should clarify this. Also, automation is _much_ easier via the help of the OS, so use BAT or shell scripts depending on Windows or unix-like systems, respectively.

Comment: See for example (not only my answer, of course) to this question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256859/create-a-pdf-with-lots-over-a-hundred-images

Comment: Without a minimal document, we have no clue what your set up is and can only guess what might work or not. If the names of the images were also in the other file, for example, you could pull them in with their captions in order. Arranging them, though, would depend on your class and page layout (obviously).

Comment: I would like to add a hugh number of images to an latex document. Let's assume I already sorted them and have text file that includes a description for the image. Lets say, picture00.jpg presents and apple, first line in the text file would be "This is a nice example for an apple", picture01.jpg shows a banana, second line in the text would be "This picture shows a banana" and so on. Each sentence is different!

Answer (score 1):

I’d create a [macro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) for inserting images and call it with as few arguments as possible. If you are dealing with a very large amount of images, you might want to look in to automating the creation of the `.tex` file, for adding macro command calls.

My code assumes images `image-1.png`, `image-2.jpg` and `image-3.jpg` are in the same directory as the `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\image}[2]{%
  \begin{figure}[h]%
    \centering
    \includegraphics{#1}%
    \caption{#2}%
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}

Mauris a sapien fringilla, interdum sapien non, dapibus erat.

\image{image-1}{Description 1} % this is one of the lines that could be automatically generated

Quisque dolor mauris, molestie ut convallis sit amet pharetra.

\image{image-2}{Description 2} % this is one of the lines that could be automatically generated

Pellentesque porttitor eleifend porta. Duis tincidunt purus felis.

\image{image-3}{Description 3} % this is one of the lines that could be automatically generated

Suspendisse blandit pretium tempus. Vestibulum vitae lacus sed.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You assume that the caption is the same as the name of the image.  So `\image` should have two different arguments.

Comment: You’re right. Answer updated!